# Adonisjs restore token model migration

Tags: adonis.js

By default when you create a new Adonisjs project there is already a ready Token model migration with the necessary values. I deleted it. How can this migration be restored?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to create a new project, and take from there (I just thought there was some kind of command to restore the Token migration).
token migration:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class TokensSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('tokens', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('users')
      table.string('token', 255).notNullable().unique().index()
      table.string('type', 80).notNullable()
      table.boolean('is_revoked').defaultTo(false)
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('tokens')
  }
}

module.exports = TokensSchema
```

User model:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Hash')} */
const Hash = use('Hash')

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class User extends Model {
  static boot () {
    super.boot()

    /**
     * A hook to hash the user password before saving
     * it to the database.
     */
    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (userInstance) => {
      if (userInstance.dirty.password) {
        userInstance.password = await Hash.make(userInstance.password)
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * A relationship on tokens is required for auth to
   * work. Since features like `refreshTokens` or
   * `rememberToken` will be saved inside the
   * tokens table.
   *
   * @method tokens
   *
   * @return {Object}
   */
  tokens () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Token')
  }
}

module.exports = User
```